# Reference for periodic solution of linear differential system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, periodic-functions

I am looking for a reference (article, book) about the following results :

Let $A(t)$ be a $(n,n)~ T-$periodic matrix, i.e. $A(t+T) = A(t) ~\forall t$

Similarly, let $B$ be a $T-$periodic map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ i.e. $\exists T >0 , \forall 1 \leqslant i \leqslant n,  B_i(t+T) = B_i(t)$

Then, the first order linear differential system $$\dot{Y}(t) = A(t)Y(t) + B(t)$$ admits a $T-$periodic solution.

I understand that this is close to Floquet theory in which $B$ is chosen to be $0_{\mathbb{R}^n}$

I keep finding results on slightly different/more general problems. (ODE systems with impulse for instance, [see here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/334156289_o_c_omega_c_-Periodic_solutions_for_time_varying_impulsive_differential_equations), or nonlinear ode systems, [see also here](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0893965909003486?token=EBA0ADCEA424B896D806E1DBC3FBC95800AB3B9B2B848D4895BF0CC143AFE4CE9A3F0C30C7E3CDE8A2376DEA15D39FA9), which might work ?)... Can someone point me toward literature encompassing this result ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the chapter on periodic coefficients in Linear Ordinary Differential Equations by Coddington and Levinson. There is a section on first order inhomogeneous systems.

Comment: Thank you. Theorem 4.6-4.7 was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Nufeu No problem at all. Good luck.